# why <button onClick={this.props.onClick}> is different from <button onClick={(e) => {this.props.onClick(e)}}> here?

Tags: reactjs

I found the following code in this [post](https://cdb.reacttraining.com/react-inline-functions-and-performance-bdff784f5578).([sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/v38y6zk8ml)) I am not sure why these buttons behave differently.

One possible explanation is: Because Button's render method is not invoked for updating, the first button's click handler remains the same. However, this.props of the Button instance has changed to include the new onClick prop. In other words,if the props of a ***component element*** is changed, ***nextProps*** will finally become ***this.props*** even when ***shouldComponentUpdate*** returns false.

```
const submit = val => alert(val);
class App extends React.Component {


state = { val: "one" }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ val: "two" })
  }

  render() {
    return <Form value={this.state.val} />
  }
}

const Form = props => (
  <Button
    onClick={() => {
      submit(props.value)
    }}
  />
)

class Button extends React.Component {
  shouldComponentUpdate() {
    // lets pretend like we compared everything but functions
    return false
  }

  handleClick = () => this.props.onClick()

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.props.onClick}>This one is stale</button>
        <button onClick={() => this.props.onClick()}>This one works</button>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>This one works too</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you get any errors? Or just unresponsive?

Comment: No errors,but with different output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your explanation is correct on that when `ShouldComponentUpdate()` returns `false`, the `Button` component does not re-render on props change.

In the first `<button>` element, the `onClick` event is `this.props.OnClick` which is actually the function `() => { submit("one"); }` at the moment of the initial rendering. `"one"` is here because at this particular time point in the React lifecycle, `Form`'s `props.value` evaluates to `"one"`. Note that the function gets executed has nothing to do with `Button`'s `props`.

In the second `<button>` element, however, the `onClick` event is  `() => this.props.onClick()`. Regardless whether the `Button` component gets re-rendered, it is always the `this.props.onClick()` that get executed, where `this.props` changes when the parent components get state/props updates.

In the case of `ShouldComponentUpdate()` returning `true`, `Button` component will re-render on props updates. The first button's `onClick` event becomes a new function `() => { submit("two"); }` on the re-render triggered by the `App` component's state change. The two button elements' `onClick` event functions are never the same function, although they appear to produce the same result.

Answer (score 0):

`<button onClick={this.props.onClick}>` Will call your onClick function and send an `event` object as its first parameter. This is the equivalent of doing this :

```
<button onClick={event => { this.props.onClick(event) }}>
```

`<button onClick={() => this.props.onClick()}>` Will set what your onClick function returns as the onClick function... It is the short syntax of the following code :

```
<button onClick={() => { return this.props.onClick() }}>
```

What you may be looking for is this : `<button onClick={() => { this.props.onClick() }}>`

In this case, clicking will simply call your function without sending any arguments

I suggest reading [this documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) to know more about arrow/anonymous functions and their syntax

Comment: If shouldComponentUpdate in the Button component returns true, the first button will produce the same response as the second one. It's not about the arguments I think. But thanks for pointing out the subtle difference.