# What is the difference between "onClick = { () => this.props.onClick() } and onClick = {props.onClick }?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was following the React tutorial [here](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html#function-components)

Please note "onClick" attributes in the following two code snippets.

In the snipped below, an arrow function is assigned to it which calls the onClick() function passed to it in props.

```
  class Square extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <button
        className="square"
        onClick={() => this.props.onClick()}
      >
        {this.props.value}
      </button>
    );
  }
}
```

But when the class Component is converted into a functional component, the onClick attribute is assigned just the reference of the onClick function passed in props.

```
function Square(props) {
  return (
    <button className="square" onClick={props.onClick}>
      {props.value}
    </button>
  );
}
```

Why is this so? I am confused.

Comment: Here's a good explanation of the differences.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/54057917/8628497

Answer (score 1):

In class based component, the props are a property on the class instance itself. Hence you access them via `this`. In a functional component, the props are passed into the function as an argument.

You can read up on the basics of class based and functional components [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html).

Also, welcome to the site!

Answer (score 0):

When you define a component using an ES6 class, a common pattern is for an event handler to be a method on the class.

**function prototype approach:**

```
function Square(props) {
  return (
    <button className="square" onClick={props.onClick}>
      {props.value}
    </button>
  );
}

and you bind the state() in constructor using this: 

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    
    // This binding will help you to read "this." in the function
    this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
  }

onClick() {
// u can read this here
}
```

**Arrow function approach**

one other way of doing the same things is: In the below approach you don't have to bind in constructor and use arrow function instead. inside the function, **this.** will have the state.

```
onClick = () => {
// u can read this here
}
```

Both are just two approaches. Arrow function approach and function prototype approach

Comment: I did not understand why you have added a constructor in the function prototype approach. There is no constructor in the original code.

Comment: Having a constructor in functional prototype approach will help you to read this.state inside your method. You can read this.props and this.state inside your functional component.